# Csv file to dataframe - reads special character

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am reading csv file using below mentioned code. 
`df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv',sep=';',header=None)`

df contains values as below. All column values have been merged into single column.Attaching image of output below.The values to be splitted across multiple columns While reading the csv itself.Kindly help how to solve this. [image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You have erroneously specified the separator to be `';'`.  You should make `sep=','`, and you will see it properly split.

Comment: I have tried with sep=',' , it's throwing an error as follows: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 25 fields in line 147361, saw 27